# Execute child component action in the parent using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am having two components, App and a panel. On button clcik, I add panel to the screen and all the actions corresponding actions inside of the panel is handled in the Panel component ( Actions are expand, collapse and close). Can I somehow execute the same actions inside of the app component using `useImperativeHandle` hook using ref's. Also can I execute `onClose` method inside of the `Panel` component, here i am actually as a callback.

https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-demo-card-6ywop7?file=/src/Panel.jsx:0-985

Can someone help me here

App

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Panel from "./Panel";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [card, setCard] = useState({
    cardId: "",
    cardBody: null
  });
  const ref = useRef();

  const handleClick = (cardId, cardBody) => {
    setCard({ cardId, cardBody });
  };

  const { cardId, cardBody } = card;
  return (
    <>
      <div className="main">
        <button onClick={() => ref?.current?.expandBtn()}>Open from out</button>
        <button onClick={() => handleClick("Panel 1", <h1>h1</h1>)}>
          Add Panel 1
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => handleClick("Panel 2", <div>div</div>)}>
          Add Panel 2
        </button>
      </div>
      {cardBody && (
        <div className="cards-container">
          <Panel
            key={cardId}
            cardId={cardId}
            cardBody={cardBody}
            onClose={() =>
              setCard({
                cardId: "",
                cardBody: null
              })
            }
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Panel

```
import React, { useImperativeHandle, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {
  faSquareMinus,
  faRectangleXmark
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

export default function Panel(props) {
  const [isMinimized, setIsMinimized] = useState(false);
  const { cardId, cardBody, onClose, ref } = props;
  const expandRef = useRef();

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    return {
      expandBtn: () => expandRef.current.onMaximize()
    };
  });

  const onMaximize = () => {
    setIsMinimized(!isMinimized);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className={isMinimized ? "card-min" : "card"}>
        <div className="card-actions">
          <span onClick={onMaximize}>{cardId}</span>
          {!isMinimized && (
            <FontAwesomeIcon
              icon={faSquareMinus}
              onClick={() => {
                setIsMinimized(true);
              }}
            />
          )}
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faRectangleXmark} onClick={onClose} />
        </div>
        <div className="card-body">{cardBody}</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can the child's function from the Parent using `useImperativeHandle`. What your implementation is missing is `forwardRef`. passing `ref` as props won't work. What you have to do is forward the ref from child to parent.

```
const Panel = React.forwardRef(function (props, ref) {
const [isMinimized, setIsMinimized] = useState(false);
const { cardId, cardBody, onClose } = props;

const onMaximize = () => {
  setIsMinimized(!isMinimized);
};

useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
  return {
    expandBtn: onMaximize
  };
});

return (
  <>
  <div className={isMinimized ? "card-min" : "card"}>
    <div className="card-actions">
      <span onClick={onMaximize}>{cardId}</span>
      {!isMinimized && (
        <FontAwesomeIcon
          icon={faSquareMinus}
          onClick={() => {
            setIsMinimized(true);
          }}
        />
      )}
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faRectangleXmark} onClick={onClose} />
    </div>
    <div className="card-body">{cardBody}</div>
  </div>
  </>
);
})

export default Panel;
```

Pass the ref from the App

```
function App() {
  const [card, setCard] = useState({
  cardId: "",
  cardBody: null
 });
const ref = useRef();

const handleClick = (cardId, cardBody) => {
  setCard({ cardId, cardBody });
};

const { cardId, cardBody } = card;
return (
  <>
   <div className="main">
    <button onClick={() => ref?.current?.expandBtn()}>Open from 
   out</button>
    <button onClick={() => handleClick("Panel 1", <h1>h1</h1>)}>
      Add Panel 1
    </button>
    <button onClick={() => handleClick("Panel 2", <div>div</div>)}>
      Add Panel 2
    </button>
  </div>
  {cardBody && (
    <div className="cards-container">
      <Panel
        ref={ref}
        key={cardId}
        cardId={cardId}
        cardBody={cardBody}
        onClose={() =>
          setCard({
            cardId: "",
            cardBody: null
          })
        }
      />
    </div>
  )}
  </>
 );
}
```

This might help https://blogsbyarjun.hashnode.dev/how-to-update-childs-state-from-parent-in-react-1

Comment: Doesnt look like its working, can you update the sandbox in question?

Comment: Codesandbox seems to be updated and working.